# How to block a website from crawling my site without knowing their IP address

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-crawler, robots.txt

There's a spam site that is an exact replica of my site. They continuously crawl my site and literally update / add content within 20 min (literally all 30k+ urls). After some research, I'm positive that they're crawling my site and storing it on their server.

They use CloudFlare which makes it so I can't know their true IP address. Can I somehow block them from crawling my site (VIA .htaccess or something) just by knowing the domain name?

Comment: welcome to the internet.

Comment: Would creating a whitelist with a robots.txt file work?

Comment: @ChrisEvans you think a site copying another site is going to obey a robots.txt file ?

Comment: Which is why I asked if it would work, and did not tell that it would. Good point.

Comment: If your site is powered by PHP, you could write IP addresses to a cache/table, and refuse to a serve a page if more than x/hits per minute are requested. Crawlers will easily achieve, say, 30 hits/minute, but a human just isn't going to be able to read them at such a rate.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible the server they run their crawling script from is completely separate from the server they host their clone on, even if they weren't using Cloud Flare.

However, if they're crawling all that content, it should be pretty obvious in your server's access logs. If you don't know where those are, talk to your hosting provider. Then look for the most common IP addresses listed, and try blocking them with something like this:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
Deny from x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Would that work if it's the CloudFlare IP though? Wouldn't I have to know the true server IP?

Comment: the IP in your log, is the IP you would block. but if they know what they are doing, that's not going to help

Comment: Like I say, where the clone is hosted has nothing to do with where they're crawling from. Imagine this crude setup: I save a web page to my PC, and e-mail it to you; you upload it to your website. No amount of looking at your website would stop this process, but the logs will show me accessing the page. Obviously, it wouldn't be like that in reality, but the only thing that matters is who is accessing your website, not where they are sending the result.